# Why is this using concat operator

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby but am pretty sure these things are equivalent. But I'm making a chance to an important script and just wanted to be sure please.

This is what they have now:

```
def generate_names options
  names = []

  name = options.name
  sen = options.sen
  ari = options.ari

  options.targets.each do |target|
    names << "#{name}" + " Test " + "#{target}"
  end

  names
end
```

This is what I want to change it to, notice on the line `names <<` I removed the `+`'s. This is exactly the same right? I even did a test on equality but just want to make sure.

```
def generate_names options
  names = []

  name = options.name
  sen = options.sen
  ari = options.ari

  options.targets.each do |target|
    names << "#{name} Test #{target}"
  end

  names
end
```

Aside I tried this in `irb` but its giving error:

```
"#{name}" + " Test " + "#{target}".eql?("#{name} Test #{target}") ? "equal" : "not"
```

Error given is:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of false into String
    from (irb):20:in `+'
    from (irb):20
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this individually:

```
names << "#{name}" + " Test " + "#{target}"
```

This is really irregular code. `"#{name}"` is going to be equivalent to `name` if that's a string value, so the quotes are extraneous, and worse, create another string that gets thrown out immediately. This one line creates four strings alone.

The other is better:

```
names << "#{name} Test #{target}"
```

This creates one string and inserts it. Interpolation is almost always better than concatenation because it creates less garbage.

Your `irb` test is flawed:

```
"#{name}" + " Test " + "#{target}".eql?("#{name} Test #{target}") ? "equal" : "not"
```

This evaluates the `.eql?` part first on *just* `target` which is obviously not a match so it evaluates to:

```
("#{name}" + " Test " + false) ? "equal" : "not"
```

Which is going to fail because you can't combine `false` and a string.

The way to test this is to force a particular evaluation order:

```
("#{name}" + " Test " + "#{target}").eql?("#{name} Test #{target}") ? "equal" : "not"
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!! Even for the irb note. SO is blocking me from accepting answer for 7 more minutes. The person before me was senior, so I was so hesitant. I really appreciate your speed!